# How to make an alkaline wax mixture?

Tags: ph, wax

I want to treat a wax so that it has an alkaline pH of at least 10. I tried just mixing sodium hydroxide with beeswax but the sodium hydroxide reacted with the beeswax and changed its properties. I want the wax to retain its natural properties and not be chemically altered by the pH-increasing component. How can I do this?

If it matters, the ideal wax for my purposes is [carnauba wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnauba_wax) which is a wax that comes from the leaves of a tree, but beeswax could work as well. It would be nice to have a method that would work for any kind of wax.

Comment: Possibly adding an organic base that is miscible with the wax e.g. triethylamine

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=ghdAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=alkaline+wax&source=bl&ots=t2aDPJ6tmC&sig=ACfU3U2YRDajFoR_p-rkAA-FP6PYcU_1PQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1laTulrXhAhUC0awKHY1jAykQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=alkaline%20wax&f=false) from a very old text (pages 279-280) suggests boiling the wax in an alkaline solution. This method may be specific to that wax described as a new vegatable wax from a laurel like shrub from the forests of Para and Bahia. Please explain the application. Why do you want the wax to be alkaline? What are you going to do with the wax?